# MVC3 enable textbox using razor engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP, we can set the property for `Textbox` as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtbox1" enable=False></asp:TextBox>
```

and in C# code we write:

```
txtbox1.enable=True;
```

How can we do the same work in MVC3?

Comment: you don't. you use pure css attributes. there is no concept of server side controls

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method a bit more sophisticated like this.

In the MVC3 controller you can define the boolean to control the TextBox

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.isTextBoxEnabled = true;

    return View();
}
```

In the .cshtml you can verify the state of the boolean and add or not the disabled attribute to the newly created `<input type="text" />`

```
@{
    var htmlOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if (!ViewBag.isTextBoxEnabled)
    {
        htmlOptions.Add("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("txtbox1", "", htmlOptions)
```

Or you can also set it strongly typed in your model (in case you avoid the ViewBag)

Comment: This way you personalize better in the controller the behavior of the showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBox("SomeText","", new { disabled = "disabled" } )
```

Comment: Bt It will Disable textbox Parmanetaly...i want to enable it on button click

Comment: Well, if you want to change it "dynamically", e.g. (click on come check box on the same page which will enable text box), you have to use Java Script (I recommend jQuery) and change CSS properties of text box. So, it's all on client side.